# Accessing Macintosh HD from Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dual-boot

So after I upgraded my MBP to Yosemite, I have lost dualboot. After a long struggle, I finally reinstalled refind to work properly. Unfortuantelly, when I use Ubuntu, I cannot access Macintosh HD drive anymore...[image: The error I get when I try to acce]
Is anyone having a same problem? If so, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Is hfsplus compiled into your kernel?

Comment: Could you please add the messages from `dmesg` and possibly the error output when you try to run the `mount` command from command line?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install hfsplus libhfsp0 libguestfs-hfsplus hfsprogs hfsutils`

Answer (score 3):

First, if you intend to write to the HFS partition from Ubuntu, you need to [disable journaling](https://support.apple.com/en-md/HT204435) on your Mac

On your Ubuntu install [`hfsprogs`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/hfsprogs) tools

```
sudo apt-get install hfsprogs hfsplus libhfsp0 libguestfs-hfsplus hfsutils
```

Check your partition as montioned [@Adam Zahran](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/100992/adam-zahran) :

```
sudo fsck.hfsplus -f /dev/sdXY
```

Mount Mac partition:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/your_mount_point
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdXY /mnt/your_mount_point
```

Comment: This is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me,
I ran:

```
sudo fsck.hfsplus -f /dev/sda2
```

and then tried again and it worked perfectly.

Note: You should replace `/dev/sda2` to whatever corresponds to your Macintosh partition.

Comment: Is that safe? Could that cause issues macos?

Comment: Never caused issues to me. But I don't understand what exactly the command does. So I wouldn't claim to know if it's completely safe under all circumstances. But then again, it worked perfectly fine for me causing no issues.