# Access Macintosh HD from Ubuntu - Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, osx, disk, macintosh

I've followed [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167197/accessing-macintosh-hd-from-ubuntu) instructions and now I'm able to access my Machintosh HD from Ubuntu, the problem is that I can't access the folder I need (example Desktop), it say that I haven't enough permissions to access the folder and I see the folder with an "X" on it. I've tried to use

```
gksudo nautilus
```

It works but I can't run the terminal every time I have to access a file on my HD. Is there a solution to edit the permissions permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the ownership of the folder by:

```
sudo chown -R username:groupname /mount/mac/Desktop
```

Replace username with your user-name.

Comment: And if the device is read only?